# How to tell if 2D context on offscreen canvas is available?

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas

I'm trying to use offscreen canvas for rendering in webworker, which works perfectly fine in Chrome, but it seems that 2D context is not yet available in Firefox. How do I know that in advance? By the time I get to creating the context, it is already too late and the original canvas is no longer functional for drawing.

Basically what I'm doing

```
const offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
worker.postMessage({canvas: offscreen});
...
// in worker
canvas.getContext("2d") // exception!
// but there's no fallback now, because we already called transferControlToOffscreen
```

Edit: somehow it didn't occur to me to create another canvas and make it offscreen before "experimenting" with the main ones. That works, but seems like a hack.

Answer (score 1):

The context returned by `OffscreenCanvas.getContext('2d')` is an [*OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#offscreencanvasrenderingcontext2d) instance.
Browsers that will support this call, will have this interface available, so all you need is:

```js
const supports = typeof OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D === "function";

console.log(`Your browser ${supports ? "supports" : "doesn't support" } the 2d context of the OffscreenCanvas`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate both `getContext` and `getContext('2d')`:

```
function isCanvasSupported(){
  var elem = document.createElement('canvas');
  return !!(elem.getContext && elem.getContext('2d'));
}
```

Comment: 2D context is available on regular canvas, but not offscreen.

Comment: the OffscreenCanvas.getContext() method returns a drawing context for an offscreen canvas, or null if the context identifier is not supported. No exception has to be thrown.

Comment: It throws an exception with name NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.

Comment: Another workaround can be retrieve browser and version instead of  testing getContext or even better enclose the check in a try/catch so you can safely manage and distinguish errors